# Commands and the Custom Shortcut Keys

Tags: shortcut-keys

In Ubuntu 16.04 I have added many custom shortcut keys to launch various applications such as Skype or Firefox.

In the case of Skype I have simply put the word `skype` in the command box. But when I put any terminal command in that box the shortcut key is ignored.
Just for the sake of argument I put `echo 'abcd'` in the command box and assign <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>5</kbd> to it - nothing happens when I use that shortcut key.
I also tried to launch bash script and also python script from the command box of Customs Shortcut Key and again got nothing when I used the assigned shortcut key.

Are there certain restrictions on what can go in the command box of Custom Shortcut Keys? Or am I not using the command box correctly?

Comment: Maybe the shortcut key for Ctrl+Alt+5 is already exists? Please try a different one

Comment: that action was to echo 'abcd' in the terminal -- it is a just a test

Answer (score -1):

You need a console to be able to execute shell commands. If you are using `gnome-terminal` you can execute a command with `-e` - so try to assign your command like:

```
gnome-terminal -e 'top'
```

Comment: Your example works.  But  try the command 'ls -l' and you will see it doesn't work

Comment: @elmclose right, but the question is not about reading console output but about executing a scripts. Proposed solution answers your question in current form

Comment: My main objective is to run a bash or python script. For example how can I run ~/myscripts/test.sh using Custom Shortcut Key?

Comment: @elmclose `gnome-terminal -e ~/myscript/test.sh;read -n 1`. The 'read -n 1' waits for key press.

Comment: Doesn't work. We shouldn't have to anything more than putting the script file name in the command box -- just as we put the word firefox in the box and it is launched when we use the designated shortcut key. To run a python script I expect to be able to put in the command box ~/my_python_scripts/test.py  and for bash script I should be able to put in bash ~/my_bash_scripts/test.sh